# Create web page protected by credential stored on Access db

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I've been trying for quite a while to set up a protected page on my website which should be accessible only to users having credentials, which I've stored within an Access database. I'm basically following the istructions I found on Microsoft Support.
Unfortunately I'm stucked with getting the connection string to work. I keep getting the error that "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Basically, I've created a Logon.asp file which collects user credentials and send them to another file Validate.asp. This file should connect to my Access DB and check if the credentials exist and consequently allow/deny access.

The code I've written in the Validate.asp is the following:

```
<%
Response.Buffer=true

'The following three lines of code are used to make sure that this page is not cached on the client.
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1

Dim userid
Dim Pwd
'Assign the user ID to this variable. The user provides the user ID.
userid= Request.Form("UID")
'Check whether userid is an empty string. If it is empty, redirect to Logon.asp.
'If it is not empty, connect to the database, and validate the user.

if userid <> "" then
    pwd = Request.Form("passwd")

    Dim Cn
    Dim Rs
    Dim StrConnect

'Specify the connection string to access the database.
'Remember to change the following connection string parameters to reflect the correct values
'for your SQL server.
Set Cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("myaccessdb.accdb")
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open "Select * from Users where uid='" & userid & "'",Cn
'Check to see whether this user ID exists in your database.
    If Not Rs.EOF then
        If strcomp( pwd, Rs.Fields("password").value , 1) = 0 then
'Password is correct. Set a session variable, and redirect the user to a Default.asp page
'or the main page in your application.
            Session("UID") = userid
            Response.Redirect "Default.asp"
            Response.End
        Else
'Password is incorrect. Redirect the user to the logon page.
            Response.Redirect "Logon.asp"
            Response.End
        End if
    Else
'If the user is not in your database, point him or her to the Register.asp page
'so that he or she can register at your Web site to access your application.
        Response.Redirect "Register.asp"
        Response.End
    End if
Else
    Response.Redirect "Logon.asp"
    Response.End
End if

%>
```

Any clue on what the problem might be?

Comment: By any chance - are u running this on 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` cannot read `.accdb` files, so you're going to have to install the Access Database Engine (ACE) redistributable on the server (available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)), and then use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

You'll need to install the appropriate version for your environment: 32-bit or 64-bit. My guess is that you'll need 64-bit because your page didn't complain that the `.accdb` file was an "unrecognized file format", it said that the "Provider could not be found." Jet OLEDB is always available in the 32-bit space and is never available in the 64-bit universe, so I'm guessing that IIS is running your script in the 64-bit environment. (The server's administrator will be able to verify that before he/she installs the ACE driver.)